# Deleting the commands in run in xp?

Tags: windows-xp

how can i delete what I've written in run without restarting the computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) can do it.

[image]

Select only the "Run (in Start Menu)" option, and it should do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Use registry editor (regedit).

Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU` and delete all values under that key.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear all recent Run dialog entries without manually modifying the registry or installing additional programs.

See http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/clear-recent-commands-from-the-run-dialog-in-windows-xp/ for walkthrough /w screenshots.